# extract everything between brackets regex

Tags: regex

Input:

```
[asa,[sasa]]<br>
[asasas,asasas,[]]
```

How can I extract text between brackets such that the output for the give input is this:

```
asa,[sasa] <br>
asasas,asasas,[]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify if the input will always start with [ an end with ]?

Answer (score 0):

This should work `(?<=\[).+(?=\])`

It uses lookbehind and lookahead to find the [ and ] characters and matches whatever is in the middle.

Test it here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l1QLYu/1/)

Comment: `\[(.*)\]` is enough

Comment: @Onyambu this may be true, but dealing with capture group is then mandatory, while Jorge. V solution allows to directly get the match.